# References are not pointer in php?

Tags: php, reference

I am new to php and learning it from php.net. Can anyone tell in the summary why does that page (http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php) says **What references are not** & **References are not pointers**.

I am beginner so please can anyone explain me in simple and easy words ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In simple words, references are aliases.

A variable in PHP is stored in two pieces: the name and the value. The name points to the value.

```
$x = 2;
$y = $x;
$z = &$x;
```

When `$x = 2;` is executed, the name `x` is stored in the symbol table of the current scope and the value `2` is stored in a `zval` (don't ask, it's the internal name of a data structure that stores a value in PHP).

When `$y = $x;` is executed, the name `y` is stored in the symbol table of the current scope and the value of `$x` (`2`) is copied into a new `zval` structure.

When `$z = &$x;` is executed, the name `z` is stored in the symbol table of the current scope but a new `zval` is not created. Instead, `z` is set to point to the same `zval` as `x`.

The memory used by the variables `$x`, `$y` and `$z` looks like this:

```
+---------+                +---------+
|    x    | -------------> |    2    |
+---------+                +---------+
                                ^
+---------+                     |      +---------+
|    y    | -------------------------> |    2    |
+---------+                     |      +---------+
                                |
+---------+                     |
|    z    | --------------------+
+---------+
```

When a value is passed by reference to a function or a function returns a reference the same things happen, only the names are stored in different symbol tables (remark the ["current scope"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the explanation above).

Let' see this code:

```
function f(& $z) {
    $y = $z;
    $z = $z + 2;
}
$x = 2;
f($x);
```

After `$x = 2;` the memory looks like this:

```
+---------+                +---------+
|    x    | -------------> |    2    |
+---------+                +---------+
```

During the execution of function `f()`, the memory looks like this:

```
+===== global ====+
|   +---------+   |            +---------+
|   |    x    | -------------> |    4    |
|   +---------+   |            +---------+
+=================+                 ^
                                    |
+====== f() ======+                 |
|   +---------+   |                 |      +---------+
|   |    y    | -------------------------> |    2    |
|   +---------+   |                 |      +---------+
|                 |                 |
|   +---------+   |                 |
|   |    z    | --------------------+
|   +---------+   |
+=================+
```

`y` and `z` are stored in a different symbol table than `x` and they are removed (together with the entire symbol table that contains them) when the call to `f()` returns.

When `y` is removed, its value is also removed because there is no name that points to it any more. But, because the value pointed by `z` is also pointed by `x` (`$z` is an alias), the value is not removed together with `z` and it survives the function call. `f()` modifies the value using `$z`; and this change is visible in the main program through the variable `$x`.

The things happen in a similar way when a function returns a reference. The function returns a value that is not copied but a new name that points to it is created into the symbols table of the calling code.

Comment: So what is the story of referencing the **passing by reference** into the function??

Comment: more about [zval](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/internal_types/zvals.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below can tell the difference between PHP reference and C pointer:

In PHP:

```php
<?php
    $a = 0;
    $b = &a;
    echo $a; //0
    unset($b); // unset $b
    echo $a; //0 it's OK
?>
```

In C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int a = 0;
    int* b = &a;

    printf("%i\n", a); //0
    free(b);              // free b
    printf("%i\n", a); //get error: *** error for object 0x7fff6350da08: pointer being freed was not allocated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to study Language C pointers if you have any doubt about what they are.

Anyway, this is a very simplified explanation:

References are not the memory addresses that point variables, but they are only a way to pass a parameter to a function and return that parameter modified if the function alter it.